# How to scrape data from Datastore.prime using vba

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this website http://www.whoscored.com/regions/252/tournaments/2/england-premier-league

When I use inspect element I see that data is in table format as shown in picture below.

[image]

The source code has the data in this format.

[image]

> DataStore.prime('stagefixtures', $.extend({ stageId: 12496, isAggregate: false  }, calendar.parameter()), [[959688,1,'Monday, Dec 21 2015','20:00',13,'Arsenal',0,167,'Manchester City',0,'2 : 1','2 : 0',1,1,'FT','1',0,1,112,0]
>   ,[959683,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','12:45',96,'Stoke',0,32,'Manchester United',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,13,0]
>   ,[959615,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','15:00',24,'Aston Villa',0,29,'West Ham',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,6,0]
>   ,[959625,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','15:00',183,'Bournemouth',0,162,'Crystal Palace',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,10,0]
>   ,[959635,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','15:00',15,'Chelsea',0,27,'Watford',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,15,0]
>   ,[959645,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','15:00',26,'Liverpool',0,14,'Leicester',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,15,0]
>   ,[959655,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','15:00',167,'Manchester City',0,16,'Sunderland',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,4,0]
>   ,[959691,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','15:00',259,'Swansea',0,175,'West Bromwich Albion',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,5,0]
>   ,[959698,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','15:00',30,'Tottenham',0,168,'Norwich',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,8,0]
>   ,[959665,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','17:30',23,'Newcastle United',0,31,'Everton',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,7,0]
>   ,[959674,4,'Saturday, Dec 26 2015','19:45',18,'Southampton',0,13,'Arsenal',0,'vs',,0,1,,'-1',0,1,11,0]
>   ]);

This code is supposed to scrape data from the table format but I don't how to do it in this case.

```
Option Explicit

Sub WeeklyFixtures()


 Dim IE As Object, obj As Object

 Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer
 Dim elemCollection As Object

 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 With IE
 .Visible = True
 .navigate ("http://www.whoscored.com/regions/252/tournaments/2/england-premier-league")
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

 Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop

ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Clear

 Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)

        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
    Next t

 End With

 Set IE = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA to retrieve the data? A simple `web query` worked on my computer just fine. Just go on the `Data` menu to `Get External Data` and select `From Web`. There you can enter the URL you gave us and select the table you want to retrieve. You can even set the query to refresh every `xx` seconds.

Comment: @Ralph I can't find the `next ->` symbol near the table

Comment: When I try to open the site in IE 11 it does not finish loading, the table is empty. In Firefox it works fine. Does the site work for you in IE? In the screen shot you used Firefox, did you try to open the page in IE manually?

Comment: @dee  In IE I get all the tables but when querying in excel I don't have that next sign along with the tables.

Comment: The table `id="tournament-fixture"` is being created dynamically. The webpage HTML code downloaded from server doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetWhoscoredData()

    Dim strCont, arrRows, strComma, arrQuots, i, arrCols

    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.whoscored.com/regions/252/tournaments/2/england-premier-league", False
        .Send
        strCont = .ResponseText
    End With

    strCont = Split(strCont, "'stagefixtures'")(1)
    strCont = Split(strCont, "[[")(1)
    strCont = Split(strCont, "]);")(0)
    strCont = Replace(strCont, vbCrLf, "")
    strComma = Mid(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)
    arrQuots = Split(strCont, "'")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrQuots) Step 2
        arrQuots(i) = Replace(arrQuots(i), ",", strComma)
    Next
    strCont = Join(arrQuots, "")
    arrRows = Split(strCont, "],[")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrRows)
        arrCols = Split(arrRows(i), ",")
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Replace(arrCols(2), strComma, ",")
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Replace(arrCols(3), strComma, ",")
        Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Replace(arrCols(14), strComma, ",")
        Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Replace(arrCols(5), strComma, ",")
        Cells(i + 1, 5).NumberFormat = "@"
        Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = Replace(arrCols(10), strComma, ",")
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Replace(arrCols(8), strComma, ",")
    Next
    Cells.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

The output it gives for me is as follows:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Excel 2016? There you should be able to get it with: `Data` --> `New Query` --> `From Other Sources` --> `From Web`. There you can enter your URL. If you record all of that you get even the corresponding VBA code.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code ? I can't find the yellow next sign on the table that I need. Also is that excel or access that you are using ?

Comment: I am using Excel 2013